# Mutually exclusivity in Problog

Tags: prolog, probability, mutual-exclusion

We have

- 4 different storage spaces, and
- 5 different boxes (named `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4` and `b5`) which they wanted to put in this storage spaces.

Each storage space can be filled with only one unique box at a time.
*But `B5` has a special condition which allows to be used in multiple storage spaces at the same time.

Each box has specific weight as assign to it (`b1`:4, `b2`:6, `b3`:5, `b4`:6 and `b5`:5).

Each box has a specific probability to be filled in to the storage spaces (`b1`:1, `b2`:0.6, `b3`=1, `b4`=0.8, `b5`=1).

We try to get the probable content of the storage spaces and their probabilities if the total weight is 22. ! (which we will use this as an evidence mechanism)

For example :

```
SS1 - b2(6)
SS2 - b5(5)
SS3 - b4(6)
SS4 - b5(5)
Where the total weight will be 22
```

And the probability of this content.

In my code bellow I get the answer for one of the probable content as `totalboxweight(b2, b5, b4, b5, 22)` which is okay for me. It means first box `b2` is in first storage space, `b5` is in second storage space and so on.

Here is my code so far, I add comments also to explain my intentions

But I need help to update it add the probabilities and apply some of the conditions I talked about.

```
box(b1,4).
box(b2,6).
box(b3,5).
box(b4,6).
box(b5,5).    % I tried to define the boxes but I dont know how to assign probabilites to them in this format    

total(D1,D2,D3,D4,Sum) :- 
    Sum is D1+D2+D3+D4. % I defined the sum calculation

totalboxweight(A,B,C,D,Sum) :- 
    box(A,D1), box(B,D2) , box(C,D3), box(D,D4),    
    total(D1,D2,D3,D4,Sum). % I am sum up all weights

sumtotal(Sum) :- 
    box(A,D1), box(B,D2) , box(C,D3), box(D,D4), 
    total(D1,D2,D3,D4,Sum). % I defined this one to use it as an evidence

evidence(sumtotal(22),true). % if we know the total weight is 22 

query(totalboxweight(D1,D2,D3,D4,22)). % what is the probable content
```

I am using an online Problog editor to test my code. [Here](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/problog/editor.html) is the link.

And I am trying to do it in Problog not Prolog, so the syntax is different.

[image: some results of the code]

Right now with the help of answers I overcome some issues, the problems I still have ;

- I couldn't apply probabilities
- I couldn't apply the condition ( Each storage space can be filled with only one unique box at a time. But `B5` has a special condition which allows to be used in multiple storage spaces at the same time.)

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: How do the answers to your linked duplicate question not apply?

Comment: `box(B1)` is the same as `box(_)`—anything is a box. You must mean `box(b1)`. Even fixing that, `boxweight(4) :- box(b1)` is a disaster. There is no way for the information that you're talking about `b1` to exit `boxweight(4)`. You must mean `boxweight(b1, 4).` The use of logical-or in `boxweight(5)` is also very crazy. I would suggest you stop, back up, reread your notes or a tutorial, because you cannot brute force your way through Prolog like this. `evidence(sumtotal(22), true)` also looks like several misunderstandings.

Comment: Thank you for your response I changed the code and add the results. I think it will make more sense now.